# how to create an ionic-button with multi line text ,wrapped text in ionic v6/v5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5, ionic6

I had a problem creating an ionic-button with multi-line text in ionic v6/v5, the problem was that the whole text was appearing in one line and part of the text was not shown. like the example in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ng-tabs-7v3bcf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.page.ts)

```
 <ion-button expand="block" size="large">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</ion-button>
```

Answer (score 5):

so basically the fix was adding the class `ion-text-wrap`, that goes as below ,from [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities#text-modification):

```
<ion-button class="ion-text-wrap" expand="block">__LONG_TEXT__</ion-button>
```

this would increase the height of the button and make the button wrap around the text. I did not find that in the documentation while searching explicitly in that wording.
The example also added in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ng-tabs-7v3bcf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.page.ts)